# Multiple compiled instances of same Java program

Tags: java, compilation, jframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Class Files filename$1.class… etc Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073088/java-class-files-filename1-class-etc-question)

I wrote a batch file to compile the java program and execute it. When I open the file location (via GUI), I see many .class files of the same file.

For example, say I have a file called "acView.java"

I see 3 compiled .class files - "acView$1.class" "acView$2.class" and "acView.class"

What do the $1 and $2 stand for? Why are they present?

The .java file is a JFrame if that's important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$1` simply means that class is an `anonymous` class and the number 1 is generated by the compiler. When you have two anonymous classes, it will have something like `YourClass$1.class` and `YourClass$2.class` in the compiled classes.

From your code, I believe you are implementing some `Listener` anonymously.

If you dont want compiler generate multiple classes, you move the code to normal class.

Comment: Could elucidate a little more or provide a link with detailed information?

Yes! I'm implementing a clickListener to a button. So, more listeners more "anonymous" classes?

Comment: @Torcellite Correct, most probably you implement anonymously.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Yes, don't define classes scoped by a top level class. But the real question is why would you want to avoid it.

Comment: Just curiosity. I wanted to know if there was a solution.

Comment: @Torcellite there is no problem at all, spend more time on other bugs :)